# I'm having problems with my @media queries

Tags: html, css, web, scale, media

I'm having problems with my @media queries. If I put my website online via github it won't scale and if I test the website in webstorm (jetbrains) it works fine. Can someone help me please?

Website link: https://conor-v.github.io/

Code link: https://github.com/conor-v/conor-v.github.io

Comment: Can you clear your browser cache and reload the live website page? Is it better?

Answer (score 1):

Happy to help! Your website seems to scale just fine though.

Can you maybe elaborate on which elements where styles are not added correctly based on the media query you have?